# MySQL query - select postcode matches

Tags: mysql

I need to make a selection based on the first 2 characters of a field, so for example

`SELECT * from table WHERE postcode LIKE 'rh%'`

But this would select any record that contains those 2 characters at any point in the "postcode" field right?  I am in need of a query that just selects the first 2 characters. Any pointerS?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is correct. It searches for postcodes *starting* with "rh".

In contrast, if you wanted to search for postcodes containing the string "rh" anywhere in the field, you would write:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE postcode LIKE '%rh%'
```

**Edit**:

To answer your comment, you can use either or both `%` and `_` for relatively simple searches. As you have noticed already, `%` matches any number of characters whereas `_` matches a single character.

So, in order to match postcodes starting with "RHx " (where x is any character) your query would be:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE postcode LIKE 'RH_ %'
```

(mind the space after `_`). For more complex search patterns, you need to read about regular expressions.

Further reading:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pattern-matching.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Many thanks for your response.

Yes it seems that query is selecting any postcode field starting with 'RH'. This is the issue I am having:

Let's say I only want postcodes that start with RH1, for example:

RH1 3JS
RH2 7YH

But my query would also select:

RH16 3NP 
RH17 3TH

Is there a way to stop the selection after 3 (or any number) of characters?

Many thanks

Comment: Many thanks Anax for the code and the links, i have got the majority of the query working how I would like now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE '%rh%'` will return all rows with 'rh' anywhere

`LIKE 'rh%'` will return all rows with 'rh' at the beginning

`LIKE '%rh'` will return all rows with 'rh' at the end.

If you want to get only first two characters 'rh', use MySQL SUBSTR() function
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: This is very helpful, MySQL SUBSTR() looks promising

Answer (score 0):

Dave, your way seems correct to me (and works on my test data). Using a leading % as well will match anywhere in the string which obviously isn't desirable when dealing with postcodes.

Comment: Thanks! yep it does work correctly, but I have further comments (see above)

Comment: I haven't tested it but you might have some success with '_'. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pattern-matching.html